# Preventing an onClick Event from happening multipe times (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, animation, callback

I'm just starting with jQuery and web development in general, so, please forgive any naive mistakes.  I'm trying to have a button that causes an animation to occur.  Namely, this animation is simply moving an 'h2' header from left to right and then back again (and trivially changing the color).

The issue I was having with the following code was that if the user clicked on the button multiple times it would cause the button to continue past the turn-around points.  I learned that this was an async problem and tried using a callback function in the animation call to reenable the button functionality.

As you can see, I've addressed the issue by setting the queue:false variable.  As I'm still new at this, is there a SIMPLER way to do this?

Thanks for your help!

```
var toTheRight = true;
$('#animation').click(function () {
    var header = $('h2')[0].style.left.toString();
    var headerNum;
    if (header.length < 5) {
        headerNum = 0;
    }
    else {
        headerNum = +(header.substring(0, header.length - 2));
    }
    if (headerNum >= 450) {
        toTheRight = false;
        $('h2').css("background-color", "green");
    }
    if (headerNum < 100) {
        toTheRight = true;
        $('h2').css("background-color", "orange");
    }
    var modified;
    var stringified;
    if (toTheRight) {
        modified = Math.round((headerNum + 100) / 100) * 100;
        strigified = modified + "px";
        $('h2').animate({
            "font-size": "3em",
            "width": "50%",
            "left": stringified
        }, { queue: false, duration: 1000 });
    }
    else {
        modified = Math.round((headerNum - 100) / 100) * 100;
        stringified = modified + "px";
        $('h2').animate({
            "font-size": "3em",
            "width": "50%",
            "left": stringified
        }, { queue: false, duration: 1000 });
    }
});
```

Comment: Just so i understand, you're wanting the user to only be able to trigger the event once regardless how many times they click the button?

Comment: The user can trigger the event as many times as desired.  So, rapid mouse clicking on the button is OK, but I don't want the animation to happen 25 times without finishing the first call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can wrap you function in a if like that :

```
$('#animation').click(function () {
    if(!$('h2').is(':animated')){
         //your function
    }
})
```

**EDIT:**

As roasted said, you could do this :

```
$('#animation').click(function () {
    if($('h2').is(':animated')) return;
    //your function
})
```

Comment: oh yes, forget this! :)  But seems better just to do at top of function:  if($('h2')is(':animated')) return;

Comment: Well that's only a personnal preference, no perfomance gain either way. But I agreed it would work.

Comment: should it be if(!$('h2').is(':animated')){}?   I'm getting a syntax marking w/o the .

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon  it is just to avoid to have to wrap all the code ;)

Comment: Thanks! I'll go ahead and do that and eliminate some of the rounding code as its unneeded. The way I had it you could actually get some pretty funky animations going on, ha. I'll mark this as answered.